# Remove Portion of Query String using JS based on their value without page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I remove just certain parameters from an URL based on their parameters?
For example, If I want to programmatically remove any parameter sets that contain the value "all" i.e. when an Ajax event completes.

www.foobar.com/page?year=all&language=all&gender=female
to:
www.foobar.com/page?gender=female

Using JS or jQuery.

Comment: That query string is both incorrect. You can't have multiple `?` in your query string, and you second doesn't have a `?` at all.

Comment: @putvande corrected

Comment: _"I want to programmatically remove any parameter sets that contain the value "all""_ , _"www.foobar.com/page?year=all&language=all&gender=female to: www.foobar.com/?gender=female"_ Why is `"/page"` not included in expected result?

Answer (score 0):

```
var queryParameters = {}, queryString = location.search.substring(1),
    re = /([^&=]+)=([^&]*)/g, m;

while (m = re.exec(queryString)) {
    queryParameters[decodeURIComponent(m[1])] = decodeURIComponent(m[2]);
}

// Add new parameters or update existing ones
queryParameters['newParameter'] = 'new parameter';
queryParameters['existingParameter'] = 'new value';
location.search = $.param(queryParameters);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Handy function to parse the URL and get a map of the query parameters
function parseQueryParameters(url) {
  var qp = {};
  if (!url) {
    return qp;
  }
  var queryString = url.split('?')[1];
  if (!queryString) {
    return qp;
  }

  return queryString.split('&')
    .reduce(function(m, d) {
      var splits = d.split('=');
      var key = splits[0];
      var value = splits[1];
      if (key && value) {
        m[key] = value;
      }
      return m;
    }, qp);

}

//Function to build a url given a map of query parameters
function buildUrl(url, queryParams) {
  if (!url) {
    return null;
  }
  if (!queryParams) {
    return url;
  }
  return Object.keys(queryParams)
    .reduce(function(m, key, i) {
      m += ((i === 0 ? "?" : "&") + key + "=" + queryParams[key]);
      return m;
    }, url)
}

function cleanUrl(url) {
  //If no URL was provided, do nothing
  if (!url) return;

  //Parse and get all query parameters as a map
  var qp = parseQueryParameters(url);

  //Create a new map to hold the filtered query parameters
  var newQp = {};

  //For each query paremeter check the value and add only the required ones to the new map
  //PS: You can also use map/reduce/filter to do this
  //Using a simple for loop here for clarity
  var keys = Object.keys(qp);
  for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    var currentKey = keys[i];
    //Add only if parameter value is not 'all'
    if (qp[currentKey] !== 'all') {
      newQp[currentKey] = qp[currentKey];
    }
  }
  
  //Build new URL from filtered query parameters
  return buildUrl(url.split('?')[0], newQp);
}

//Call cleanUrl with URL 
cleanUrl("http://example.com?a=all&b=all&c=none"); //Returns "http://example.com?c=none"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `URL()` constructor, `URLSearchParams()` to get query string of URL as an `Array` of arrays of properties and values corresponding to query string parameters, `Array.prototype.filter()` and `RegExp.prototype.test()` to remove query string parameters from array, and `URLSearchParams()` again to reconstruct filtered query string parameters

```js
let src = "https://www.foobar.com/page?year=all&language=all&gender=female";
let url = new URL(src);
let re = /all/;
let props = [...new URLSearchParams(url.search)]
            .filter(([key, prop]) => !re.test(prop));
url = url.origin + url.pathname;
let params = new URLSearchParams();
props.forEach(([key, prop]) => params.set(key, prop));
url += "?" + params.toString();

console.log(url);
```

Comment: Thanks @guest this is a great partial answer but does not update the URL.

Comment: @sam use `history.pushState(null, null, ("/page?"+params.toString()));`

Comment: @Sam What do you mean by _"does not update the URL"_?