# Remove Portion of Query String based on a variable parameter value

Tags: javascript, regex, query-string

I am using the following code (with the help of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46742991/remove-portion-of-query-string-using-js-based-on-their-value-without-page-reload)) to remove query string parameters that contain "all"?

It turns:

https://www.foobar.com/page?year=all&language=all&gender=female
into
https://www.foobar.com/page?gender=female

How can I modify the code to use a variable instead of "/all/"? I want to be able to easily switch out which parameter to remove.

**Existing code (working but no variable):**

```
let src = "https://www.foobar.com/page?year=all&language=all&gender=female";
let url = new URL(src);
let re = /all/;
let props = [...new URLSearchParams(url.search)]
            .filter(([key, prop]) => !re.test(prop));
url = url.origin + url.pathname;
let params = new URLSearchParams();
props.forEach(([key, prop]) => params.set(key, prop));
url += "?" + params.toString();
```

**New code (not working)**

```
let parametervariable = "/somefoovariable/";
let src = "https://www.foobar.com/page?year=all&language=all&gender=female";
let url = new URL(src);
let re = parametervariable;
let props = [...new URLSearchParams(url.search)]
            .filter(([key, prop]) => !re.test(prop));
url = url.origin + url.pathname;
let params = new URLSearchParams();
props.forEach(([key, prop]) => params.set(key, prop));
url += "?" + params.toString();
 variable):**
```

The new code gives the following error: "Uncaught TypeError: re.test is not a function"

Comment: What is `variable`?

Comment: @guest271314 added.

Comment: You can use `RegExp` constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `RegExp` constructor

```
let parametervariable = "somefoovariable";
let re = new RegExp(parametervariable);
```

Comment: @Sam Are you expecting the forward slashes to be part of the `RegExp`? `/all/` is a `RegExp` literal. `new RegExp("all")` results in `/all/`